# The inversion map on regular normal subgroup normalizes whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, solution-verification

The following exercise is taken from [Permutation Groups](https://books.google.de/books?id=4bNj8K1omGAC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Peter Cameron.

> Let $G$ be a primitive group of odd order. By the Feit-Thompson Theorem, $G$ is soluble, and so a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is abelian. Show that $N$ acts regularly.
>   Identify $\Omega$ with $N$ as in Section 1.7. Show that the permutation of $N$ given by $n \mapsto n^{-1}$ normalises $G$.

The identification he is refering to works by using that $N$ acts regular, hence for some fixed $\alpha$ we have a correspondence between the elements $\beta \in \Omega$ with the unique $n \in N$ such that $\beta = \alpha^n$.

That $N$ acts regularly follows easily, for as $\alpha^{Ng} = (\alpha^g)^N$ the $N$-orbits form a system of blocks, or by noting that $G_{\alpha}$ is maximal and we must have $G = G_{\alpha} N$ as $N \le G_{\alpha}$ could not be because the action is faithful.

So as I understand the exercise the inversion map is also a (self-inverse) permutation of $N$ (or $\Omega$ by the identification of both). So it asks to show that this permutation normalises $G$ in $Sym(\Omega)$, i.e. $\varphi \in N_{\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)}(G)$
with $\varphi : N \to N$ being the inversion map. But this means that $((n^{-1})^g)^{-1}$
equals some permutation in $G$, but as conjugation acts as automorphisms on $N$ we have
$$
 ((n^{-1})^g)^{-1}
 = ((n^{-1})^{-1})^g 
 = n^g.
$$
So this is quite a trivial property, and it always holds if we have some regular normal subgroup (which could also be non-abelian). But the assumptions seem to be more specific, and also my solution seems really simple.

So have I understood anything wrong? The complicated assumptions and the fact that my argument is essentially very trivial make me somehow suspicious about it...

Comment: Once you've identified $\Omega$ with $N$, it's not true that $G$ acts on $N$ by conjugation. Otherwise, every element would fix the identity and the group would not be transitive!

Comment: If fact, $N$ acts on itself not by conjugation, but by (say right) multiplication. So, for $m\in N$, we define $\hat{m}\in\mathrm{Sym}(N)$, such that, for all $n\in N$, $n^{\hat{m}}=nm$. Now, $\hat{N}=\{\hat{m}\mid m\in N\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(N)$ isomorphic to $N$. Now, compute $\hat{m}^\varphi$, viewed as an element of $\mathrm{Sym}(N)$. You'll see that, this is still an element of $\hat{N}$, but you will need the fact that $N$ is abelian.